# Checking position of an entry in an index MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I have a query using pymongo that is outputting some values based on the following:

```
cursor = db.collect.find({"index_field":{"$regex":'\s'}}
for document in cursor:
  print document["_id"]
```

Now this query has been running for a long time (over 500 million documents) as I expected. I was wondering though if there is a way to check where the query is in its execution by perhaps finding out where the last printed "_id" is in the indexed field. Like is the last printed _id halfway through the btree index? Is it near the end?

I want to know this just to see if I should cancel the query and reoptimize and/or let it finish, but I have no way of knowing where the _id exists in the query.

Also, if anyone has a way to optimize my whitespace query, that would be helpful to. Based on the doc, it seems if I would of used ignorecase it would of been faster, although it doesn't make sense for whitespace checking.

Thanks so much,
J

Comment: Your first question is not clear to me. Regarding optimization, when you isnert the document, keep a boolean/flag in the doucment if index_field is having whitespace, and make a sparse index on that flag/boolean. Now your new query will be `find({flag: true})` or `find({flag: {$exists: true}})`

Comment: If you have a cursor, and you are iterating through it, is it possible to find out the position of an _id in the cursor. That's all. If you see, I'm printing out the _id. So I want to take that _id, and figure out where it would be in the cursor object.

Comment: You can't do that, because the cursor documents are fetched in batches. Normally the batch size is limited to some size or no of documents. So, until and unless you iterate (and collect) all the documents from the cursor, its impossible to find an `_id` inside the cursor. You can try this command. `cursor = db.collect.find({"index_field":{"$regex":'\s'}}; cursor.count(); cursor.objsLeftInBatch();`

Comment: oh that makes sense.. well the query is over. Thanks for your help and lets never speak of it again

Comment: 1. It won't work, you need another slash for escaping, as I answered.
2. Note: `cursor.count()` is a slow op, so it's best to avoid it, **if possible**.

Answer (score 1):

## Query optimization

Your query **cannot** be optimized, because it's an inefficient`$regex` search that's looking for the space `\s` in the the document. What you can do, is to search `$regex` for a prefix of `\s`, e.g.

```
db.collect.find({"index_field": {"$regex": '^\\s'}})
```

[Check out the notes in the link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/#op._S_regex)

### Indexing problem

> `$regex` **can only use an index efficiently when the regular
>   expression has an anchor for the beginning (i.e. ^) of a string and is
>   a case-sensitive match**. Additionally, while `/^a/`, `/^a.*/`, and
>   `/^a.*$/` match equivalent strings, they have different performance
>   characteristics. All of these expressions use an index if an
>   appropriate index exists; however, `/^a.*/`, and `/^a.*$/` are slower.
>   `/^a/` can stop scanning after matching the prefix.

---

## DB op's info

Use `db.currentOp()` to get info on all of your [running ops](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.currentOp/#currentOp.progress).

Comment: Problem is, sometimes  the whitespace does not anchor the beginning or end. But its run through

Comment: @jwillis0720 Try my edited reply, if you don't need to use indexing and it's important for you to get all the fields with at least one space, than you should remove the anchor.